# Why face filling is not fully complete?

Tags: bezier-curves

I make curve using *Bezier Curve*, when i tried to fill the face at one of the end of curve, the face is not fully filling like this [image]

Even though i have convert it from curve to mesh and apply the scale, the face is still not fully filling.
What is the problem? Here is the blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/f8c84469b0a74c6eb1b646b27c2e40a3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some vertices that are overlapping (image below), you need to select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* (or <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* in 2.7?) and you'll be able to fill the face.

[image]

Comment: Is the mesh's split is possible because of overlapling mesh?

Comment: actually I've just checked and your object is made of 2 separate meshes, at the junction the vertices overlap but they don't merge, you need to merge them

Comment: When i remove doubled it, it remove 340 vertices, but i am confused. How is it possible to have overlapping vertices when you convert curve to mesh?

Comment: yes thzt's weird, are you sure you have not ripped the mesh along these 2 edges?

Comment: what is rip mesh? i don't remember doing anything weird, i just add Offset, Extrude, Depth and Resolution.. that's all. Then I convert the curve into mesh.

Comment: if you select an edge or an edge loop and press V it will rip the mesh, so you either did it on these 2 edge loops accidentally or it's a bug

Comment: Maybe, though i not quite sure about that... anyway thank for your help